# Set X and Y values of UILabel using NSLayout

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, user-interface, nslayoutconstraint

I am adding a UI Label and I am trying out programmatic UI code. I set up my label using this code:

```
let titleLabel: UILabel = {
    let lb = UILabel()
    lb.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    lb.textAlignment = .center
    lb.numberOfLines = 1
    lb.textColor = UIColor.black
    lb.font=UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22)
    lb.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    return lb
```

and then added constraints using this code:

```
func setupTitleLabel() {


    titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    titleLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    titleLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    titleLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.superview!.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    titleLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.superview!.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

I call this function later on. However, I am not sure how to change to X and Y values. Currently, it is set to the middle of the page  for both X and Y, but how would I move it up to the top.

Comment: use this two `titleLabel.superview!.leadingAnchor` , `titleLabel.superview!.topAnchor` instead of `titleLabel.superview.centerXAnchor` and `titleLabel.superview!.centerYAnchor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you are using `titleLabel.superview!.centerYAnchor` wrongly if you need pin your label to top of your label superview you need use `titleLabel.superview!.topAnchor` instead

**replace this**

```
titleLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.superview!.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

**by this**

```
titleLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.superview!.topAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: I am trying to add text to see where the label is and lbl.text = "string" is not displaying text :/

Comment: are you sure that your UILabel was added in your desired view? i don´t see the `self.view.addSubView(self.titleLabel)` anywhere @user8480321

Comment: then add your UILabel to the correct UIView, you must have your desired results @user8480321

Answer (score 0):

What I understand the case is that the label is in the centerX and centerY, and you want it to be at the top of the superView later.If so,I think you can use `var centerYAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?`

```
centerYAnchor = titleLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.superview!.centerYAnchor)
centerYAnchor.isActive = true
```

And when you want to change the label at the top later,you can set `centerYAnchor.isActive = false` and set the label's topAnchor.

```
 titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.superview!.topAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: I am simply trying to add a title to the page. I am trying to set the Y value something at the tip of the page but it doesnt seem to be working. With your method, it only slighly increases in Y value from the middle

Comment: I think centerXAnchor,heightAnchor,widthAnchor and topAnchor, the 4 anchors are  enough to make the label in the position you wanted.